# css - What's difference between display:none; and visibility:hidden;?

Tags: html, css, difference

What's exactly the difference between `display:none;` and `visibility:hidden;` they both do the same thing.

What sorcery is that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Display:none` hides the element from the page, and the space it would take up on the page can be used by other elements. `visibility:hidden` hides the elements, but it continues to consume the space it normally would.

Comment: You can accept an answer in 4 mins :P